# Link in Node-red

Tags: raspberry-pi, node-red

I am testing with my new Raspberry Pi and starting with the Node-red and I have encountered an obstacle.

I try to make a link to another web and I don't know how do it.

With de dashboard I have done a botton but I need that When I press the button that redirects me to another web.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Well i would execute a bash script when you press the button.

To execute the bash script you need the "exec" node, where you have to tell him the adress to the script.sh. in the script.sh you write something like "epiphany http://example.com" with the epiphany browser.

Maybe you can enter directly "epiphany http://example.com" directly into the exec node.